# Active Directory RoleProvider - Principal.IsMemberOf throws PrincipalOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, roleprovider

I have created the following method in a custom Active Directory RoleProvider:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
             ContextType.Domain, null, domainContainer))
    {
        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
             principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
        foreach (string acceptibleGroup in GroupsToInclude)
        {
            GroupPrincipal adGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                 principalContext, acceptibleGroup);
            if (user.IsMemberOf(adGroup))
                results.Add(acceptibleGroup);
        }
    }
    return results.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
}
```

It only checks against a white list of roles which are used in my application. The problem is that if the user is not a member of one of the roles, I get a `PrincipalOperationException` when the

```
if (user.IsMemberOf(adGroup))
```

line is executed. I would expect this to simply return `false if the user is not in the group. What is going wrong here?

**EDIT:**
As and aside, if I call `user.GetAuthorizationGroups()` and attempt to loop through the results, I get a COMException - The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

Comment: And did you check if adGroup is null or empty when this happens?

Comment: Yeah, I specifically added a group to which I don't belong to my white list. The code correctly finds the group and assigns it to the adGroup variable but it blows up when the IsMemberOf method is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Principal.IsMemberOf()` and `user.GetAuthorizationGroups()` are using `tokenGroups` attribute to determine the group membership.

You need to make sure the account you used to run the program is added to `Builtin\Windows Authorization Access Group` in order to access `tokenGroups` attribute.

See this [MSDN KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331951) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to work around this problem with the following:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username) 
{ 
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList(); 

    using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, domainContainer))
        {
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
            foreach (string acceptibleGroup in GroupsToInclude)
            {
                GroupPrincipal p = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, acceptibleGroup);
                if (p.GetMembers().Contains(user))
                    results.Add(acceptibleGroup);
            }
        } 

    return results.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[]; 
}
```

However it is not exactly efficient as it pulls all the members of a group back. I am sure there is a better solution to my problem and hopefully someone will post it here!